# req.files undefined in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My goal is to upload to s3 without rely on any middle-where like multer. THis is my view:

```html
<form role="form" action="/send" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My api using express.js:

```js
router.post('/register_', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files) // undefined
});
```

I do `req.body.photo` it shows a string, but how do I stream the file if `req.files` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html form is not proper. There should be enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to submit files from the form. Also I would suggest to use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) in node application to accept files in a route.

Comment: what is that for?

Comment: Busboy is for accepting file in your routes. Please refer to the link I have provided.